# how is this substitution string working?

Tags: sed, kerberos

I am working with kerberos configuration (specifically the krb5.conf file) and there is a specific section called auth_to_local mappings and it is defined here:

http://web.mit.edu/Kerberos/krb5-1.9/krb5-1.9.5/doc/krb5-admin.html

A typical mapping entry looks like this:

`auth_to_local = RULE:[1:$0\$1](^DOMAIN\.COM\\.*)s/^DOMAIN\.COM/DOMAIN/`

The man page states the exact syntax, but basically the above line would look for a UPN like:

user@DOMAIN.COM and convert it to DOMAIN.COM\user and see if it can match DOMAIN.COM and if so, substitute in just DOMAIN.  So, end result would be DOMAIN\user.

However, we have an entry (that works) in this format:

`auth_to_local = RULE:[1:$0\$1](^DOMAIN\.COM\\.*)s/^DOMAIN\.COM\\//`

Seemingly, it is substituting the DOMAIN.COM with some kind of null value, but I can't decode what this `"\\//"` syntax means.

I'm not sure if this rule uses standard sed type syntax to substitute...can someone wager some guesses as to the interpretation of this?

Comment: I would assume `\/` is a forward slash, escaped by a backslash.

Comment: but the format of the substitution part is 's/<string to find>/<string to replace>' so the literal translation of that line would then be to replace 'DOMAIN.COM\' with `//` which would be null, right?  Your answer was nothing knew to me, but for some reason it made me look at this in a new light that makes sense for the end application we are seeing.  thanks.

Comment: knew = new ... some reason I can't edit :/

Answer (score 0):

It's just matching DOMAIN.COM/    The \/ is needed to note that it's a normally special character to be treated as part of the string. Note: \ / is not capital V.

Comment: Thanks - FrankPI's comment already turned me on to looking at it differently.  It isn't matching `DOMAIN.COM/` it is actually matching DOMAIN.COM\ and replacing it with null since there is nothing in between the two `/` characters.  I've got it all now!

Comment: @user2700942 Glad you figured it out.